# Get output after matrix operation

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a matrix A:

```
[[ 1  2]
 [ 3  4]
 [ 5  6]
 [ 7  8]
 [ 9 10]]
```

And I have matrix B:

```
[[1 0 0]
 [0 1 0]
 [1 0 0]
 [0 0 1]
 [0 1 0]]
```

And my desired Output is :

Matrix C:

```
[[1 0 0]
 [0 3 0]
 [5 0 0]
 [0 0 7]
 [0 9 0]]
```

i.e I would like to get first Column of Matrix A, and Substitute its values in Matrix B, where it says "1". Problem is that I need to do it using **Matrix operations** in Numpy, i.e without using Loops.

So far, I have done following.  Please help me do it in easy steps

```
mat_A = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]])
mat_B = np.array([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0]])

mat_A1 = np.zeros(mat_B.shape) 
mat_A1[:mat_A.shape[0],:mat_A.shape[1]] = mat_A 
mat_A1[:,1] = np.zeros(5)
print(mat_A1)

mat_A2 = np.zeros(mat_c.shape) 
mat_A2[:mat_A.shape[0],:mat_A.shape[1]] = mat_A 
mat_A2[:,0] = np.zeros(5)
print(mat_A2)

print(mat_B)
```

My Output is :

```
[[1. 0. 0.]
 [3. 0. 0.]
 [5. 0. 0.]
 [7. 0. 0.]
 [9. 0. 0.]]
[[ 0.  2.  0.]
 [ 0.  4.  0.]
 [ 0.  6.  0.]
 [ 0.  8.  0.]
 [ 0. 10.  0.]]
[[1 0 0]
 [0 1 0]
 [1 0 0]
 [0 0 1]
 [0 1 0]]
```

If I multiply, I get different output. Please help me get Matrix C.
I want to do it **`WITHOUT USING LOOP`** and only using numpy and matrix operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this..

```
C = np.zeros((B.shape))

for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    C[i,:]=B[i,:]*A[i,0]

result: 

array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 3., 0.],
       [5., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 7.],
       [0., 9., 0.]])
```

you could also do this which is a bit more generalized if the data you are providing is just an example of data you are really working on...

```
replace_val = 1

for i in range(B.shape[0]):
    for j in range(B.shape[1]):
        if B[i,j] == replace_val:
            C[i,j] = A[i,0]
```

same result

EDIT : this way works with no loops

```
vals_to_change = np.where(B==1)
C[vals_to_change] = A[vals_to_change[0],0]*B[vals_to_change]
```

same result

Comment: Thank you for sharing, but I need to do it using matrix operations, and without using any loop.

Comment: see above edit for method without loops..other than that I'm out of ideas..

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution without the use of **for loops**:

```py
import numpy as np
mat_A = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]])
mat_B = np.array([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0]])
mat_C = mat_B.copy()

mask = (mat_C[...] == 1) #Create a mask 
mat_C[mask] = mat_A[...,0] #Replace masked values by the ones in mat_A's first column

print(mat_C)
```

Create a mask and use it to index into `mat_C` to assign the values of the first column of `mat_A` to the 1's that were in `mat_B`.